# Accessing elements of returned JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to access individual elements of my JSON that I've returned from a .post method with jQuery. When I send the data to create.php, all it does is json_encode the data and put it in a json object. Here is my code:

```
$.post("pages/create.php", {user : "user1", password : "pass2"}, function(data) {
    var newArray = new Array();
    newArray = {"user":"user2","password":"pass2"};
    console.log(newArray.user);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.user);
```

The issue is that the first two console logs do what I would expect. The first one gives me:

> "user2"

The second gives me:

> "user" : "user1", "password" : "pass2"

But the third is undefined, even though I know the data JSON object has stuff in it. Is my syntax wrong? I'm just trying to access a specific element of that JSON.

Comment: can you check the ajax request using your browsers network tab and see what is happening

Comment: You can add 4th parameter to $.post() function - "json". It means that server will return json and jquery will parse it for you

Comment: Why are you creating an array, and then an object ?

Comment: Oh, and try doing `console.log(typeof data)`, and it probably reads "string" !

Comment: You seem to be confused about the differences between arrays and objects.

Comment: y, guyz r right, just add `dataType` param, moreover its necessary:
`$.post("usrl", function( data ) {}, "json");` ; more information: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `json` as fourth parameter to the `$.post()` function as

```
$.post("pages/create.php", {user : "user1", password : "pass2"}, function( data ) {
    console.log( data.user);
}, "json");
```

This will post to the create.php page and get content which has been returned in `json` format.

And make sure create.php returns jsonencoded data as:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("user1"=>"Kishor","pass1"=>"mypass")); ?>
```

Also set correct content type HTTP header for `JSON` as:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Have a look at [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type).

Comment: Just to clarify, it tells jQuery that you're expecting a JSON formatted response.  It wont actually tell the server what type of response you would like, it's totally up to the server to provide properly formatted JSON.

Comment: Yay, the data returned must be jsonencoded, I have mentioned that too.

Comment: And ideally you will have also set the header appropriately on the server side to identify the response type as `application/json`.

Comment: Awesome, unfortunately I can't try this out until I get back to work on Monday but I will give it a shot then and it should work. If not, I'll report my findings here.

Answer (score 0):

all answers given seem to be correct, i just have the feeling your JSON response might be missing the "{" and "}" .. but is just returning the properties of the object...